# Facebook Ads Total Conversion Value Mismatching with Purchase Conversion Values

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel

We are an e-commerce site and we run ads on Facebook.

We track conversions using Facebook Pixel.

When analyzing our ad performance, we've noticed there are several metrics for tracking conversion values.

We use:

**Purchases Conversion Value (Facebook Pixel)** to track purchases on our websites.

**Mobile App Purchases Conversion Value** to track purchases on our mobile apps (iOS/Android)

However, we also noticed a metric named **Total Conversion Value** that is usually larger than the sum of both web and mobile purchases. The official definition of Total Conversion Value from Facebook is:

> The total revenue returned from conversions or Facebook credit spends
>   that occurred on your website or app. This is based on the value
>   assigned to the conversion type in your pixel code.

Using brute force (listing out all possible metrics Facebook Ads Manager reports), we found the discrepancy between Total Conversion Value and SUM(Purchase Conversion Value, Mobile App Purchases Conversion Value) is coming from a metric named **Mobile App Actions Conversion Value**. Here goes its official definition:

> The total value returned from actions that occurred in your mobile app
>   as a result of your ad.

Here is the question:
What exactly is this Mobile App Actions Conversion Value?

We scanned our iOS/Android code and found we only report a conversion value when there is a purchase and those numbers are reflected in PCV and MAPCV. We don't see anywhere in our code that we would report a conversion value that is not associated with a purchase.

We've also noticed that this Mobile App Actions Conversion Value can be positive when there is no purchase. So we assume it is associate with events that occurred prior or independent to the purchase event.

Here is an example:
[image: Conversion Value Discrepancy]

As you can see the discrepancy can be huge that would total mess up our ROI calculation. Any idea on what this Mobile App Actions Conversion Value is? Or what we can do to find out what it is?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 0):

Mobile App Actions Conversion Value, including Mobile App Purchases Conversion Value, also includes the value of other app event reported by your mobile app, such as the value of Add To Cart event.

If you only care the Purchase events, just sum up those two Purchase related values as you mentioned. You can ignore the Total Conversion Value.